# In SVN + Apache, how to password protect old revisions?

Tags: apache-http-server, svn, htaccess, authorization

We have a svn repository, facaded by apache, and protected by (complex) authorizations.

At revision 1000, we are migrating lots of folders in that svn to a new structure. We thus adapt the rights to the new structure.

Because it is too complex to maintain the old rights on the old structure, I would like to simply prevent poeple to access theses revisions (older than revision 1000).

I am thinking about an htaccess allow/deny rule based on revision number. Is it feasible and/or the correct way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd say http://serverfault.com/ is better place to ask this question

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking about an htaccess allow/deny rule based on revision number

Will **NOT** work at all - Apache know nothing about revision|tree in repo

If you want totally hide old revisions - remove revisions 1-999 from repository|move to the separate repository